# How to terminate whole test in jMeter after a fixed amount of time?

Tags: automated-tests, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I wrote a windows batch script that runs a group of parametrized jMeter tests. However the test sometimes hang (should take aprox. 2 minutes, takes 5 hour for no reason - can Gaussian Random Timer cause that?). I really need the whole batch job to finish within some time bounds. So:

**Is it possible to set a maximum execution time for a jMeter test after which the whole test along with all threads is terminated?**

Note: Scheduler doesn't really do the trick (I set startup delay = 0 and duration = 20  and the test still doen't finish in under a minute).

Answer (score 3):

Do a thread dump to see what is happening as this may indicate an issue on server side.

Do you have this log in jmeter.log or in console:

```
The following non-daemon threads are still running (DestroyJavaVM is OK)
```

To overcome this:

1. configure timeouts on HTTP Sampler
2. Use scheduler and configure it to run for a duration

Comment: That's exacly what I figured out while waiting for the answer.